# Python Image Processing Syntax Error

Tags: python

I try to get familiar with a bit of image processing. I did an exercise online and I have a challenge with one of the functions, I cannot debug properly.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio

# Masking Images
photoData = imageio.imread("../images/sd-3layers.jpg")
totalRows, totalCols, totalLayers = photoData.shape
X, Y = np.ogrid(:totalRows, :totalCols)
centerRow, centerCol = totalRows / 2, totalCols / 2
distanceFromCenter = (X - centerRow)**2 + (Y - centerCol)**2
radius = (totalRows / 2)**2
circularMask = (distanceFromCenter > radius)
print(circularMask[1500:1700,2000:2000])
```

I get the following error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-28-6cc7fea28dce>", line 4
    X, Y = np.ogrid(:totalRows, :totalCols)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not know why this is actually happening? The data input seems correct to me. What is wrong with the syntax. Can you help me please?

Comment: what is `:totalRows`? what should this do?

Comment: extracting the values of photoData.shape into totalRows, totalCols and totalLayers

Comment: What did you want to do when you did `np.ogrid(:totalRows, :totalCols)`? Maybe `np.ogrid[:totalRows, :totalCols]`? (Your line looks like Ruby to me lol)

Comment: I meant the next line, I didn't see a `:list` statement ever.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ: what `:list`? I suspect that needs to be a slice inside an index.

Comment: The ':' before totalRows and totalCols look strange.

Comment: @mingganz - that's just numpy's syntactic sugar for slicing

Comment: @Amadan maybe its a shortcut or something in Numpy, it's a syntax error in python itself.

Comment: I just dont see the error reason. totalRows contains a number as well as total cols. and I the numpy fuinction ogrid does not accept

Comment: The rest of the functions work fine and numpy too.. sorry.. i missed the includes

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ: numpy *is* Python. There's nothing in numpy that is not syntactical in Python, just possibly undefined.

Comment: The reason for the error, as already said by both me in my first comment and davidlowryduda in his answer, is you have wrong parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely that you mean

```
np.ogrid[:totalRows, :totalCols]
```

This is a numpy shortcut for typical python slicing, such as

```
s = "abcde"
print(s[:3])
# prints "abc"
```

Use brackets, not parentheses.